# Entity Framework 6: Erro de Conexão

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Criei um projeto com Entity Framework 6 e um outro projeto do tipo Console Application, contendo a seguinte string de conexão no arquivo App.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=MeuDB; Integrated Security=True" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Adicionei a "ConnString" no construtor do DbContext e depois habilitei o Migrations e executei o comando "Update-Database -Verbose".

Antes de acontecer o erro abaixo, segui todos os passos para [configurar o SQL Server para acesso remoto](http://www.systematiza.com.br/site/?page_id=837).

> Using StartUp project 'MeuProjeto.Console'.
>   Using NuGet project 'MeuProjeto.Infra.Data'.
>   Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>   Target database is: 'MeuProjetoDB' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Ocorreu um erro de Local Database Runtime. Não é possível criar uma instância automática. Consulte o log de eventos do Aplicativo do Windows para obter detalhes do erro.
>   )
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
>        em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   Error Number:-1983577832,State:0,Class:20
>   Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Ocorreu um erro de Local Database Runtime. Não é possível criar uma instância automática. Consulte o log de eventos do Aplicativo do Windows para obter detalhes do erro.
>   )
>   PM> Update-Database -Verbose
>   Using StartUp project 'MeuProjeto.Console'.
>   Using NuGet project 'MeuProjeto.Infra.Data'.
>   Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>   Target database is: 'MeuProjetoDB' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Ocorreu um erro de Local Database Runtime. Não é possível criar uma instância automática. Consulte o log de eventos do Aplicativo do Windows para obter detalhes do erro.
>   )
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
>      em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>      em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   Error Number:-1983577832,State:0,Class:20
>   Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Ocorreu um erro de Local Database Runtime. Não é possível criar uma instância automática. Consulte o log de eventos do Aplicativo do Windows para obter detalhes do erro.
>   )

Comment: O erro diz que não conseguiu se conectar ao SQL Server. Você tem o LocalDB versão 11 instalado mesmo?

Comment: Eu instalei o SQL Server Management Studio v17.2 no localhost. Esse LocalDB não se refere ao localhost?

Comment: Não. Ele se refere ao serviço de LocalDB do SQL Server.

Comment: Ah, sim. vou procurar outras strings de conexão. obrigado!